# Is there any possibility to compare multiple devices LatLng to 1 device LatLng?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, notifications

In my project, there will be 2 types of user(tourguide, tourist) and all their information will be stored in Firebase. And whenever 1 of the tourist out of range(Example, 1KM) from tourguide, that particular tourist and tourguide will get notification. 
How do I compare all the tourist LatLng to the tourguide LatLng and both will get notification when out of range?

This is the current code I have for comparison distance between 1 tourguide and 1 tourist.

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng tourist, LatLng tourguide) {

    int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
    double lat1 = tourist.latitude;
    double lat2 = tourguide.latitude;
    double lon1 = tourist.longitude;
    double lon2 = tourguide.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = Radius * c;
    double km = valueResult / 1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter = valueResult % 1000;
    int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
            + " Meter   " + meterInDec);


    return Radius * c;
}
```

Comment: _"...all their information will be stored in Firebase."_ Have you done anything regarding Firebase yet? Looks like using Firebase is the main problem as you already know how to compare the locations, but now the questions seems too broad. Is there any more specific problem with Firebase?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Currently i don't find any problem with my firebase, but i want to know if there's method I can do to compare multiple LatLng to one LatLng? I heard GeoFence can do something like this but from what I know GenFence is fixed position and does not center based on user location.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer. GeoFence indeed is for a specific use case, but maybe you can use it. That would mean that each tourist's phone would set a distance to the tourguide as geofence and get a notification when exiting it. And you'd need to keep this geofence up-to-date as the tourguide moves. Otherwise you can use existing methods for calculating the distance as e.g. the `Location` class has the `distanceTo()` and `distanceBetween()` methods. Maybe some library (like [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/)) has some useful methods(?) I don't know.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I will get it a try, but GeoFence seems quite complicated.